# Is Software Engineer or Computer Science more in demand in today's job market?

Tags: job-offer

I have an offer for Computer Science as well as for Software Engineering for my undergrad. What stream should I select looking at future job market?

Comment: Everything is in demand, my friend! What are you going to do in life without cops, doctors and nurses, soldiers, lawyers, electricians, plumbers, garbage collectors and all such people? What really matters is where your interest is.

Comment: This question is too broad to be answerable.

Comment: Hey Prb, and welcome to [workplace.se]. As explained in our [help/on-topic], *"Questions looking for opinions on what to do but with no specific problem are suited for discussion boards (not a question/answer site) and generally will be closed on The Workplace"* -- we are looking for questions that are practical and answerable based on fact not opinion. If you [edit] your question to be in line with the guidelines in the [help], you may be able to get better answers to a slightly different question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: From what I've noticed, most companies cannot tell the difference between the two and will simply treat you as "programmer". My school has both programs and we take 90% of the same courses, the difference being computer science having a few more math courses, while software engineering has a few more project process courses/design/group work. I find personally as a software engineer I came out of school more prepared than the computer science students, but that is one student from one school with one example. Ask the school for the differenceAndSelectYourFavourite,TheDemandDifferenceIsNeglible

Answer (score 3):

A good company is looking for people who are - to steal a phrase - smart and get things done ( http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/06/05.html ). If you have that, then the details of your degree won't make a lot of difference; I have had twenty successful years in development on the back of pure and applied maths, and I know plenty of others who graduated in things like engineering and physics. Plus, you also have to make it through the course in one piece, so don't select it purely on the basis of vague ideas of employability (and if you can call the jobs market accurately 3 years in advance you're wasted doing programming! :) ) - do a course that you will *enjoy* and *find stimulating*.

Answer (score 2):

> Computer Science vs Software Engineering

No one from HR will care. All they will do is check the checkbox for "has a degree".

No one who will interview you for your first few jobs will care. They will be interested in how you learned and what exciting stuff you did at university.

So select the one that sounds fun.